# JOptionPane switch statement loop

Tags: java, swing, switch-statement, joptionpane

@MadProgrammer, the switch-case function stops after one choice. I can't seem to get it to go back to OnlineStore( ). I tried do-while statement. It didn’t work. It will go to default then back to the menu regardless of the input, 1 or 2.

```
        import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

        public class OnlineStore 
        {
            String[] ColorType = {"blue", "green", "black"}; 
            final int COLOURS = 3;    // t choices
            int[] Color = new int[COLOURS];
            int sum, mselect;

            public static int display_menu() // Not the main program but the main menu.
            {
                String input;
                int mselect;
                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Welcome!" + "\n\n1. Add tshirt order\n2. Edit tshirt order\n3. View current order\n4. Checkout" + "\n\nPlease enter your choice: ");
                // return Integer.parseInt(input);
                mselect = Integer.parseInt(input);
                return 0;
            }

            public OnlineStore() // Switch-case program
            {
                do 
                {
                display_menu();
                switch (mselect)
                { 
                     case 1:
                        add_t();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        edit_t();
                        break;
                    default:  // If an error is encountered.
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Oh dear! Error!");
                        break;
                }
                } while (mselect < 3);
            }

            public final int add_t()
            {  
                for (int index = 0; index < ColorType.length; index++)
                {
        <output>
                }
                return Color.length;
            }

            public final int edit_t() 
            {
                for (int index = 0; index < ColorType.length; index++)
                {
        <output>
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) // Main program
            {
                new OnlineStore(); // Call out the program.
            }

        }
```

Comment: @Codebender Actually, I don't think the OP wants the class instance field, but should be returning the value from the method and using it in the `switch` statement instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer, that's right.. Moreover the method is in a static context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First...

```
public static int display_menu() // Not the main program but the main menu.
{
    String input;
    int mselect;
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Welcome!" + "\n\n1. Add tshirt order\n2. Edit tshirt order\n3. View current order\n4. Checkout" + "\n\nPlease enter your choice: ");
    // return Integer.parseInt(input);
    mselect = Integer.parseInt(input);
    return 0;
}
```

You aren't returning `mselect`, but are returning `0`.  Instead you should probably do something more like...

```
public static int display_menu() // Not the main program but the main menu.
{
    String input;
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Welcome!" + "\n\n1. Add tshirt order\n2. Edit tshirt order\n3. View current order\n4. Checkout" + "\n\nPlease enter your choice: ");
    // return Integer.parseInt(input);
    return Integer.parseInt(input);
}
```

Next, you are using the `mselect`, which has no value to check in your `switch`

```
public OnlineStore() // Switch-case program
{
    do {
        display_menu();
        switch (mselect) {
            case 1:
                add_t();
                break;
            case 2:
                edit_t();
                break;
            default:  // If an error is encountered.
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Oh dear! Error!");
                break;
        }
    } while (mselect < 3);
}
```

but instead, you should be using the returned value from `display_menu()`

```
public OnlineStore() // Switch-case program
{
    do {
        switch (display_menu()) {
            case 1:
                add_t();
                break;
            case 2:
                edit_t();
                break;
            default:  // If an error is encountered.
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Oh dear! Error!");
                break;
        }
    } while (mselect < 3);
}
```

Be VERY wary of `static`, it's not your friend and can easily turn a nice running program into garbage.

Instead, you could do something more like...

```
public class OnlineStore {

    String[] ColorType = {"blue", "green", "black"};
    final int COLOURS = 3;    // t choices
    int[] Color = new int[COLOURS];
    int sum;

    public int display_menu() // Not the main program but the main menu.
    {
        String input;
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Welcome!" + "\n\n1. Add tshirt order\n2. Edit tshirt order\n3. View current order\n4. Checkout" + "\n\nPlease enter your choice: ");
        // return Integer.parseInt(input);
        return Integer.parseInt(input);
    }

    public OnlineStore() // Switch-case program
    {
        boolean exit = false;
        do {
            switch (display_menu()) {
                case 1:
                    add_t();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    edit_t();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    exit = true;
                    break;
                default:  // If an error is encountered.
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Oh dear! Error!");
                    break;
            }
        } while (!exit);
    }

    public final int add_t() {
        return 0;
    }

    public final int edit_t() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) // Main program
    {
        new OnlineStore(); // Call out the program.
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try.

Comment: It works! As always you are brilliant! :-) I will be very wary of 'static'. Also, where did this statement "return Integer.parseInt(input)" return the value? The main program or class. My apology in advance. I still trying to grasp the fundamentals. If you can direct me to a source for further reading I will appreciate it.

Comment: Essentially, `return Integer.parseInt(input);` is returning the value of `input` (parsed to a `int`) back to the caller, which get's picked up by `switch (display_menu()) {`

Comment: Have a look at [Returning a Value from a Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not giving mselect a value. What you probably want to do is

```
        int sum;
        static int mselect = 0;

        public static int display_menu() // Not the main program but the main menu.
        {
            String input;
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Welcome!" + "\n\n1. Add tshirt order\n2. Edit tshirt order\n3. View current order\n4. Checkout" + "\n\nPlease enter your choice: ");
            // return Integer.parseInt(input);
            mselect = Integer.parseInt(input);
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: IMHO- `static` is a poor choice, especially when the method is already capable of returning a value, indicating the required state

Comment: I agree, but I assume the OP has reasons for whatever it is he's trying to do. I'll let him decide what to do, I just gave him a fix fitting his current state.

Comment: Shame, you could have provided a more professional solution to their problem, solving their issue and teaching them some best practices at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the input into the local variable. Its scope only with the method. [local Variable scope](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Objects/local.html)

```
mselect = Integer.parseInt(input);
return mselect;
```

and assign the

```
mselect = display_menu();
```

or make the mselect as static and remove the local variable.